# Recursively check for git directory updates

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I would like to know if there is a way to determine which sub-folders under a specified directory are git projects. After which, check which of those git projects need updating via 'git fetch' or otherwise.

For example, I have a folder called development in my home folder, which holds various projects with about 10% of them using git. Rather than individually check for project updates I would like to be able to run a command which checks for any updates for all of the git folders in the development directory.

It would also be nice if it could update non-conflicting projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to get a list of all Git repos under your current directory is with the following command:

```
find . -name '.git' | xargs -n 1 dirname
```

You could then feed this into a shell script which runs your command of choice in each repository, either by changing to the directory or by using Git’s `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` arguments.

Comment: Could you explain then -n argument in the xargs command. I took a look at the man pages, however I am still uncertain as to the function it performs.

Comment: @MrAxilus xargs usually use all output as command line parameters to specified command (it is dirname in our case). -n asks to split all input 1-word pieces and call dirname for each piece.

Comment: @AlexandrPriymak, I see. Wouldn't it be better to use find's -exec argument?

Comment: @MrAxilus Thanks for the tip. -exec option is great.

Comment: The updated command would be "find . -name '.git' -exec dirname '{}' \;", without quotes.

Comment: find . -name '.git' -type d | xargs -n 1 dirname

Answer (score 3):

Here's a (hacky) one-liner for that:

```
back=`pwd`; for d in `find . -type d -name .git` ; do cd "$d/.."; git pull ; cd $back ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

In short:

```
find . -name .git -execdir git pull -v ';'
```

You can also create the following script (e.g. `update_src.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Script to pull all git repositories to the recent version.
ROOT=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2> /dev/null)
find "$ROOT" -name .git -type d -execdir git pull -v ';'
```

or create a following alias in shell:

```
alias git-pull-all='find $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2> /dev/null) -name .git -type d -execdir git pull -v ";"'
```

or in your `~/.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at android's [repo](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html). I think there's nothing android specific in it and you will be able to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Hmm, what exactly does repo do that git doesn't?